# Check if user input exist in the dataframe column value

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Example SQL query:
`my_query = SELECT a.fruits, a.colors FROM table1`

```
Table

    a.fruits    a.colors

     apple      red

     grapes     purple

     mango      yellow
```

```
DF

       fruits    colors

1      apple      red

2      grapes    purple

3      mango     yellow
```

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(my_query)
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns(['fruits','colors']))

user = args.add.lower()
conn.close()
```

*<How can I query the dataframe, to check if the user input exists in the df?>*

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-a','--add')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

User input
`python3 -a grapes`

Expected output if it exist:
`grapes, purple`

Comment: What are the column names of your table?

Comment: Are you taking user_id as input? Like, `1` or `2` or `3`?

Comment: The original names of the table columns say a.fruits, a.colors. The input would be `grapes` or any of the fruits listed. I used the argparse for another function where I will be adding that input to a bucket but I just want to show how I am getting the input.

Comment: @MayankPorwal no the numbers are not inputs, in the DF i think that is the default index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-a','--add', dest='fruit')
args = parser.parse_args()

qs = "SELECT fruits,colors FROM table1 WHERE fruits = :fruit"

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.db')
df = pd.read_sql(qs, engine, params=vars(args))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[...]$ python db.py -a grapes
   fruits  colors
0  grapes  purple
```

Comment: is there a way to query the column without having to use sqlalchemy? Additionally, I am using psycopg to connect to my redshift database

Comment: If you want to keep it simple as possible, use sqlalchemy and `create_engine` with a url like `postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]`. Else instantiate your cursor then execute the query string and use `df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())` to get your dataframe